# How to set file type association in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystems, mdi

I have a MDI application. This MDI application has lots of other tools including an editor as well. I would like to open all the ".txt" files with the editor of my MDI application, thereby making my application as the default viewer of all the ".txt" files.

Whenever the user edits a ".txt" File the MDI application should launch and a editor window should be populated with the contents of the chosen ".txt" file .

Is there a way I can do that please.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Windows API to modify file type associations for an extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446879/is-there-a-windows-api-to-modify-file-type-associations-for-an-extension)

Comment: You could also make whatever installer your using do this - after user confirmation - if something messed with my .txt association I would be pretty annoyed

Comment: @AlexK. Thats a very good point, make sure you are telling them you are changing their txt association :)

Comment: Setting a file association is a standard feature of a Setup project.  Install time is the only time you can hope to change a global association and not get whacked by UAC.

Comment: OfCourse, that is the standard procedure. I would only do the modifications after the user has allowed me to do so. 
Note : I would not like to do it via the installer. Via my code, is the way I would like to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this reg key:

```
HKCR\txtfile\shell\open\command
```

Change the default value to your program with %1 at the end for parameters. Then in your program handle the command line args to do what you want with it.

Answer (score 5):

In my application, I do this at launch:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

private void GetDefaultsFromRegistry()
{
    if (Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\MyApp", String.Empty, String.Empty) == null)
    {
        Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Classes\\MyApp", "", "My File Type");
        Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Classes\\MyApp", "FriendlyTypeName", "My Friendly Type Name");
        Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Classes\\MyApp\\shell\\open\\command", "", 
            "path\\to\\my\\app \"%1\"");
        Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Classes\\.ext", "", "MyApp");

        //this call notifies Windows that it needs to redo the file associations and icons
        SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x2000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

With all paths, names, and extensions changed to your application, of course.

Do be careful with messing with the user's .txt file association, though. I check the assignment on every launch because my application is using a custom type and is only deployed on in-house imaged systems. I don't know where your application is being deployed, but I would be very annoyed if some random utility I downloaded from the internet was constantly changing my .txt file association, and I'm sure a lot of other people would be too.

Answer (score 1):

File assocition can programmatically be done like [this](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHNY_enUS433US433&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=FileAssociationInfo) or it can be done by through registry key like [this](http://daycounter.com/LabBook/Changing-File-Associations-With-Registry-Editor.phtml)